# jquery regex negate letters

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to validate a contact number field, with that I am not allowing any letters.

### **JS FILE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var regex = /[^\d]/;
    var regex = /[^a-zA-Z]/;
    $('#contact_num').blur(function() {
        if(regex.test($(this).val()) == true) {
            alert('valid');
        } else {
            alert('invalid');
        }
    });
});​
```

### HTML FILE

```
Contact Num: <input type="text" id="contact_num" />​
```

My regex here seems to return valid if the letters comes with the digits, which must be false.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PYwLJ/1/)

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only checking a single character, though you are very close. You need anchor characters on the side.

```
var regex = /^[^a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

Comment: Thanks. Why negate `^` outside `[]`?

Comment: Outside of square brackets, `^` symbolizes the start of a string and `$` means the end of a string. By bounding our regex with those characters we tell the regex the ENTIRE string must fit these containts.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't allow only letters but allow any other characters then you should reverse your regexp and your condition:

```
var regex = /[a-zA-Z]/;
...
if( !regex.test($(this).val()) ) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PYwLJ/3/

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought of it. I think depth on `^`. :)